# How to use geohash in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-google-maps, geohashing

I am using angular google map to to create polygon and I need to convert the co-ordinates to geohash. 
  I checked around but didn't find anything on angular regarding this, So please help out any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-geohash

Comment: I need in on angular 6

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/latlon-geohash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing related with angular here. You can use any js/ts library which works for you.

Here is popular library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/latlon-geohash

In order to import javascript inside ts

```
 import * as gh from 'latlon-geohash';
```

The only thing is you wont have types. But you don't need them anyway

Comment: Its a javascript file I would need something is typescript

Comment: Why does it matter. You can use javascript as well.